# Powershell to copy the contents from particular Mercurial branch

Tags: powershell, mercurial

I am trying to download the contents from particular Mercurial branch to my local machine using powershell. I have found something following but no go. Any help?

$url = "http://testmerc01.development.local:48050/test/shortlog/502059c28165"

$wc = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient

$wc.Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.NetworkCredential '******', '*******'
iex ($wc.DownloadString($url))

Answer (score 1):

It seems working for me with following command

hg clone "repository URL" -b "branch name"